# qt qmake -tp vc to create visual studio project files

Tags: qt

I am using QT Creater 1.0.0. and QT 4.5.0 LGPL license.

I want to develop an application in QT that will run on a windows mobile 6.0.

I have created a simple project in QT and I want create the visual project files so that I can compile on window mobile using visual studio and test using the emulator.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 TS and have the windows mobile 6 SDK installed.

However, I have created my project in QT and I browse to where the project is located using QT command prompt.

I am in the root of my project and I type qmake -tp vc
I am get this output:

```
D:\Projects\PDA_Phone\PDA_Phone>qmake -t vc
WARNING: Unable to generate output for: D:/Projects/PDA_Phone/PDA_Phone//Makefile.Debug [TEMPLATE vc]
WARNING: Unable to generate output for: D:/Projects/PDA_Phone/PDA_Phone//Makefile.Release [TEMPLATE vc]
```

My directory contains the following files:

```
 Directory of D:\Projects\PDA_Phone\PDA_Phone

06/25/2009  05:37 PM    <DIR>          .
06/25/2009  05:37 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/25/2009  05:18 PM    <DIR>          debug
06/25/2009  05:17 PM               187 main.cpp
06/25/2009  05:17 PM               233 mainwindow.cpp
06/25/2009  05:17 PM               325 mainwindow.h
06/25/2009  05:17 PM             1,626 mainwindow.ui
06/25/2009  05:37 PM             5,242 Makefile
06/25/2009  05:17 PM               307 PDA_Phone.pro
06/25/2009  05:17 PM    <DIR>          qtc-gdbmacros
06/25/2009  05:17 PM    <DIR>          release
06/25/2009  05:17 PM             3,146 ui_mainwindow.h
               7 File(s)         11,066 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  10,922,962,944 bytes free
```

Can anyone tell me if I am doing anything wrong with the above. I am totally new at using QT.

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Are you sure you're using qmake -tp vc? You mentioned it twice, but your output above shows you're using qmake -t vc. (note the -t instead of -tp)

You either need to use:

qmake -tp vc

or

qmake -t vcapp

It could also be a bad QMAKESPEC environment variable.

Try this:

```
set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2008
qmake -tp vc
```

Comment: Hello, That worked after I set the QMAKESPEC. What is the QMAKESPEC and what does it do? I am wondering how can this become bad? Many thanks.

Comment: The QMAKESPEC tells qmake what platform/compiler is being used. It can point to a directory with some config files, or it can be one of the presets. I think by default when you set it up with Qt Creator that QMAKESPEC is win32-g++, so it's not so much "bad" as just never set for Visual Studio. You can find out what it is by doing echo %QMAKESPEC% at a command prompt