# QT: normal VS project file to build?

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qmake

I'm using QT (4.7.3) and I'd like to make normal VS solution/project files, build it, and step through the code with debugger to learn the code while reading tutorial...

Instead I have that yet another make qmake which supposed to be able to generate vs solution/project files but it seems that all it generates is some junk empty project files.

Here's what I did (from QT command promt):

```
cd c:\qt\4.7.3\examples\tutorial
qmake -t vcsubdirs
qmake -t vcapp
qmake -tp vc
```

but all of them generate random junk or errors...

I assume that I can also generate such solution for entire QT (from c:\qt\4.7.3) to build it from source...

What's the proper way to do it? It has tight integration with VS (designer, add-in etc) it just doesn't make sense that there is no normal solutions/project files there.

Did I do something wrong, or VS is kind of unsupported build platform? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for a few modes, like `-project`, qmake expects a valid project file to exist before you run those options. You'll also want to make sure that you're using a QMAKESPEC that corresponds to one of the MSVC versions. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043294/qt-qmake-tp-vc-to-create-visual-studio-project-files) has some good details. To summarize:

1. Create your project file
2. Set your QMAKESPEC
3. Generate the solution file from the project file

That might look something like this:

```
$ qmake -project
$ set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc2008
$ qmake -tp vc
```

`qmake -project` will regenerate the project file, so don't do that if you have modified your project file at all. The qtnode website also has some good information on [using Qt4 with visual studio](http://qtnode.net/wiki/Qt4_with_Visual_Studio).

Comment: I read that post about QT that you refer to (that's how I found out about qmake commands). I use examples\tutorial which has all these .pro files.
I didn't try that qmake -project command, instead I decided to go old school way, I downloaded src and build it myself, it seems that it's supposed to generate VS project files (at least the configure thing offers such option).

Comment: The examples aren't exactly standard as they include other project files that exist in different directories, etc. I'd suggest creating a simple project and making sure it compiles using: `qmake -project` then `qmake` then `nmake`. Once you know you have a valid project file (in standard format), then you should be able to run the above commands to generate an actual solution file.