# Compiling Qt4 projects with Visual C++ 6

Tags: qt4, visual-c++-6

I would like to know how to compile **Qt4** (preferably **qt 4.8.1**) projects with **Visual C++ 6**.
I found in [Qt4.4 Compiler Notes](http://radekp.github.com/qtmoko/api/compiler-notes.html#visual-studio-windows), that **Qt4.4** was tested **vc6 sp5**.

1. Is it possible to compile `Qt4.8.1` projects with `vc6`?
2. How to create `vc6` project from `Qt4` project?
3. How to integrate `Qt4` into `vc6 IDE`?

Comment: have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043294/qt-qmake-tp-vc-to-create-visual-studio-project-files)

Comment: I know how to create Visual Studio 2003 and above projects. The question is how to create Visual C++ 6 project.

Comment: its the same process just use `set QMAKESPEC=win32-msvc` (without year) and then `qmake -tp vc`