# Compile c++ project without makefile neither CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++

How can I easily compile a c++ project ( https://github.com/eduardovera/D-KHT ) that doesn't have any makefile neither CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Can you describe your constraints ? There is a lot of possible ways.

Comment: It has a .pro file used with QMake and qt-creator.

Comment: I just want to execute the main.cpp

Comment: I had never used Qmake, how can I do that?

Comment: Please, have a look at [qmake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) which is shipped with Qt. It generates the necessary makefiles which in turn can be used to build with make.

Comment: I just learnt that `qmake` seems to be able to generate a VS solution as well: [SO: qt qmake -tp vc to create visual studio project files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043294/qt-qmake-tp-vc-to-create-visual-studio-project-files)

Comment: The project also requires the `Qt` framework so you may want to use qt-creator at first if you don't have experience with Qt.

Comment: For future reference: [compiler-construction] is for questions involving *writing* compilers, not about using or invoking them.

Answer (score 2):

Projects that don't have a build script, and are not header-only libraries, are virtually useless. Building them manually requires issuance of dozens or hundreds of commands, and is not tractable. Build scripts are there for a reason. Use them! They make hard work easy. If you use them properly, that is.

There is some confusion in your project: Qt Creator is an IDE. You don't need it to build anything.

### Building qmake-based Projects From Command Line

#### macOS/Linux

```
# assume the git checkout is in the wc folder in the current directory
# uses system default Qt installation
mkdir build
cd build
qmake ../src
make
```

#### Windows Command Prompt

```
:: Assume the git checkout is in the wc folder in the current directory
:: BuildTools can be also Community, Professional or Enterprise - based on what
:: Visual Studio variant you have installed
:: 2019 can be 2017 (again - depends on what you got)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall x64
mkdir build
cd build
C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake ..\src
nmake
:: For faster builds, use jom instead of nmake:
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom
```

Note that the path to visual studio installation and the path to Qt installation effectively select the compiler and Qt version. Do not modify the global environment PATH! Instead, you could add a `bin` folder to your home directory, add *that* to the path, and add symlinks there to your chosen `vcvarsall.bat` and `qmake.exe`.

### CMake

But in any case - don't use qmake and make. Use `cmake` and `ninja` instead. You'd replace all `qmake` calls with `cmake`, and all `[n]make` calls with `ninja`. To pass Qt installation path to `cmake`, use the following options: `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<path to your Qt install>`

#### macOS/Linux

```
# assume the git checkout is in the wc folder in the current directory
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -GNinja ../src
ninja
```

#### Windows Command Prompt

```
:: Assume the git checkout is in the wc folder in the current directory
:: BuildTools can be also Community, Professional or Enterprise - based on what
:: Visual Studio variant you have installed
:: 2019 can be 2017 (again - depends on what you got)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall x64
mkdir build
cd build
C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin\cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64 ..\src
C:\Qt\Tools\Ninja\ninja
```

### When to Run What

#### Once in a Given Command Prompt

On Windows, the `vcvarsall` script has to run *only once* in any given command prompt window. It sets up environment variables needed to find and run the compiler and related tools.

#### Once in a Given Build Folder

The build script generators `qmake` and `cmake` need to be run only once in a given build folder. But `qmake` is abysmal at dealing with changes that go too far, so in practice you often have to re-run it manually. `cmake` normally has no such problems - it will re-run itself as needed.

#### Once Per Build

The build tool itself: `ninja`, ideally. Or `make` (on Unix), or `jom` (on Windows), or `nmake` (on Windows, if you hate yourself - it's slow).

Answer (score 0):

If a cmake support is missing for an open source project, *you can add it*.

I created one that let's you run `main.cpp`, which seemed to be what you wanted. But lacking Qt on my computer, I dropped the dependency to it. I tried with Visual Studio 2019 and it seems to work with the examples in the repo. (Note that you have to create a folder "output" before you run though.)

You should be able to clone https://github.com/eduardovera/D-KHT/pull/3 and run cmake like normal now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to compile a c++ program is to go to your terminal find where your file is stored cd into that path, and then use g++ filename.cpp. And when you run it use ./a.out.